# Implement Reactjs CRUD Application without unique ID for items

Tags: reactjs, crud

I am creating a CRUD application using Reactjs but i'm having a hard time implementing the *DELETE* feature. I used the `key={item + 1}` to generate a unique ID for every stored item in the array but I don't really know how to assess it. Here's my code...
**the LIST**

```
<ul>
  {this.state.items.map(item => (
    <li key={item + 1}>
      {item}
      <button>edit</button>
      <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>delete</button>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>;
```

**delete function**

```
handleDelete(id) {
    let items = this.state.items;
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.filter(item => items.id !== id),
    });
}
```

**state**

```
this.state = {
  input: '',
  items: [],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pas some info to handleDelete

```
handleDelete(id){
    let items = this.state.items.filter(item => items.id !== id);
        this.setState({
            items: items
        });
}


<ul>
        {
            this.state.items.map(item => ( 
            <li key={item.id}>
            {item}
            <button>edit</button>
 {/* here I send id of current item */}
            <button onClick={()=>this.handleDelete(item.id)}>delete</button>
            </li>
        ))}
</ul>
```

Update. Ignoring id you can use key  => index

```
handleDelete(key){
    let items = this.state.items.filter((item, mapKey) => key !== mapKey);
        this.setState({
            items: items
        });
}


<ul>
        {
            this.state.items.map((item, key) => ( 
            <li key={key}>
            {item}
            <button>edit</button>
 {/* here I send id of current item */}
            <button onClick={()=>this.handleDelete(key)}>delete</button>
            </li>
        ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work because my array id is generated using **key={item + 1}** ..except there's a different way I can generate id's and assess them too?

Comment: I just posted second part with key param to delete

Comment: you can generate ids, when you create that array, you plain array would be composed from objects, ex: [ { id:'some-id', value:"foo"}, { id:'some-id2', value:"bar"}]

Comment: working example https://zew1d.csb.app/ I created an sanbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-jang-zew1d